# Temporary Anti-Spam measures are now in place

Tags: discussion, spam

So you've been getting hammered. While we very much appreciate all of the hard work everyone has been doing to keep things clean, we feel like we should be making it easier for you.

Hence, effective immediately, ***the threshold of spam / abuse flags required for a post to be automatically deleted has been cut in half.*** This also has the benefit of more quickly training our spam system since that's an event that the system learns from. We've also made tweaks to deal an instant blocking weight within the system for every instance of a post being spam-flag deleted.

Or, less technically, when three of you spam-flag a post:

- It's instantly deleted.
- The originating host (and possibly nearby networks) are automatically blocked from posting.

We're going to leave this in place for at least the next 7 - 10 days. Thanks again for everything you do, and know we're watching and here to help.

Comment: *the next 7 - 10 days* can you make that 6-8 weeks?

Comment: Perhaps forever?

Comment: If these measures had been in effect for the last year, how many non-spam posts would have been erroneously deleted ("false positives")? I suspect is that the answer is "very few", or even "none". I therefore support @Kaz's suggestion that the lower threshold stay in effect for the indefinite future.

Comment: Let's see how this goes. We're keeping our options open as we continue to do some work on overhauling the spam system to deal with new types of threats.

Comment: @StephanKolassa It is very few to none. Most posts pick up at most one erroneous spam / abuse flag, rarely two, never three unless it's a targeted effort in which case that becomes a pattern of abuse and we have ways of dealing with that :) Need to run some more numbers going back more, though, but my few years as a mod on Stack Overflow was enough confidence to go ahead and do this quickly.

Comment: "So you've been getting hammered. " - have we? I've flagged a few spam posts myself, but wonder what volume does it take to be considered "hammered"?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere just eyeballing it, we're averaging about 10 spam posts per day.

Comment: I've been flagging at least one or two a day.

Comment: [NO!!!!](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BigNo) Now I need to put in twice as much effort to get the [marshal](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/marshal) badge. [Screw This, I'm Outta Here!](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ScrewThisImOuttaHere) ;-)

Comment: Do we have any stats on spam posts' uptime before deletion?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere [here](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?body=&commit=Search&feedback=&option=graphs&reason=&site=156&title=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&username=&utf8=%E2%9C%93&why=#graphs) is an overview of the amount of spam posts that made it to the site in the last month and were detected by [Smoke Detector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/wiki). It detects all spam of the 'hormone pills' variety, and most of the sneakier stuff as well.

Comment: By the way I think I saw a new type of spam answer in Programmers.SE. The question had copy/paste a part of 2 different answers and add a link at the end of the post.

Comment: @Glorfindel - hmm. Doesn't seem like a lot - I expected more. I know of many sites that truly get "hammered". Still, it's good to automate it away as quickly as possible.

Comment: @Walfrat Smoke Detector usually catches those as well, because the links in those answers link to well-known spam sites. Still, you're more than welcome to report such posts in [Charcoal HQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) and improve the filter.

Comment: @Lilienthal neither SEDE nor mods have that data (except by manually looking at deleted spam and doing the computations), so an SE employee would have to get that for us.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Shame, I think that would be a more useful metric to have than mere volume. Still, while I haven't seen it be a problem, I suppose it's nice to lower the threshold anyway.

Comment: @Lilienthal This is network wide, but (again from SmokeDetector) we have a [graph](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/graphs) of time-to-deletion for spam posts. Last graph on the page.